# Search in table where search phrase is stored in two separate rows

Tags: sql, search

I have a table of some sentences like this table:

```
  ID |   Order   | Creator_ID | text
-----+-----------+------------+------------------------
  1  |     1     |    3       | first part
  2  |     2     |    3       | second part
  3  |     5     |    1       | first part
  4  |     7     |    1       | second part
  5  |     12    |    2       | first part
  6  |     13    |    1       | second part
```

I have a complete sentence string like `first part second part` and i wanna know if such sentence exists in table or not. I don't know where this sentence should be splitted in order to make two sentences like the sentences in database. I guess this problem can be solved using `LIKE '%...' OR LIKE '...%'` SQL command but there is more conditions in this search.

I have two more search criteria, 1. two rows that are returned by this query should have the same `Creator_ID`s 2. `Order` Column of first part of sentence should have exactly `Order` of second sentence minus 1.

An example:
I search for existence of `first part second part` string in the table.

1. Rows 1 and 2 can make this sentence up. They have the same `Creator_ID` and `Order` of first part is 1, `Order` of second part is 2 and 1 = 2 - 1. They should appear in result.
2. Rows 3 and 4 can make this sentence up. They have the same `Creator_ID` **but** they don't have consecutive `Order`s.
3. Rows 5 and 6 also can make this sentence up but they don't have the same `Creator_ID`s

Other combinations like row 1 and 4 or rows 3 and 6 and etc fail at `Creator_ID` and `Order` tests, so only first and second rows should be returned by this SQL Query.

How this SQL query should be written?

- I cannot change structure of this table.
- This table is stored in an sqlite database and i'm using Django (if these pieces of information matter!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify the pairs of rows that meet your criteria by using a self-join:

```
select s1.id as id1, s2.id as id2
from sentences s1 join
     sentences s2
     on s1.creator_id = s2.creator_id and
        s1.order = s2.order - 1
where s1.text like '%first part%' and
      s2.text like '%second part%';
```